# Chartjs - group items on dohnut chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have such doughnut chart with grouped items, is it posible somehow show group name near like green - ok, yellow - issues, red - bad?

[image]

Comment: You can give same color to multiple data in chart js. Just generate data with color information and group/sort on color, before giving it to render

Comment: Why don't you just hide the legend then manually render the Green/Yellow/Red legend yourself (not using chartJS)?

Comment: well I need to show them as items, so legent should show them, but in aditional i need to show that color means as well, they already grouped by color but how to show meanings of colors?

Comment: because its to much hasle, and its only one of 10 widgets, so have like template and just atach data separately and this one need additional lvl of legend - group names

Comment: Please share the code that produces above chart. This will make it easier to others to propose a solution.